# Use multiple asset folders in xCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, assets

So I am working on a game in SpriteKit. I have a function that generates a level for the player. 
The function uses images placed in assets.xcassets to generate levels. The game has multiple themes , namely fire water and electricity. Each theme has its own set of images with the same names but each theme image set is in its separate folder/group. Is it possible for me to programmatically tell the function to use a specific folder so that I can generate levels for other themes without renaming images. Or is it possible for me to use multiple asset folders and change which one the function uses at runtime. I want to use a random theme every time the player restarts the level. [image: assets folder]

Comment: As far I know you can't keep images with the same name in same folders, and the images you access from Assets folder are not based on folders but image names.  So best way to do is keep image name based on themes and programmatically set those images based on themes.

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple asset folders in project navigator like
assets1.xcassets,
assets2.xcassets, and so on 
and the access each folder programmatically

Comment: YES! Click on Add new Files go to resources or search for asset catalog and add asset catalog name it whatever you want

Comment: It is not recommended to have 2 files with the same name,  the way the image libraries work is it does its best to find the file with the name given even if you point it to the wrong location.  I would recommend using string interpolation and using separate sprite atlases. Example `let fireblock = SKSprite(imageNamed(“fire_\(block)”)`

Comment: You could even do `let block = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:”\(level)_\(block)”)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sprite Atlas / Sprite Sheet

You can use a Sprite Atlas (also known as Sprite Sheet).

> If you don't know what I'm talking about have a look at these 2 nice videos:
>
> - [Sprite Sheets - The Movie Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crrFUYabm6E)
> - [Sprite Sheets - The Movie Pt. 2 - Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KyUqyS5MLA)

### How to use it

If you have watched the videos now you know that the main target of a Sprite Atlas is loading into the GPU all and only (as far as possible) the images needed for the current scene or level. This way drawing each frame becomes much faster because all the resources al already on the GPU and the CPU only needs to transmit the coordinates.

### Namespace

Ok but how does it solve your problem?

Xcode allows you to create a namespace for each Sprite Atlas. So you can use the same name for resources in different Sprite Atlas.

### How to create a Sprite Atlas.

This is pretty simple.

1. With Xcode open you `Asset Catalog`
2. Tap on the `+` button you see in the image below

[image]

3. Click on `New Sprite Atlas`
4. You'll se a new "Folder", that's your Sprite Atlas.

[image]
5. Now click on the  `Provides Namespace`checkbox on the right.

That's it. Now just drop your images into the Sprites folder in order to add them to your sprite atlas.

In this example I'm going to rename the Sprite Atlas as `Sprites0` and will add a red circle named `circle`.

Then

- will create another Sprite Atlas
- will check again the `Provides Namespace`checkbox
- will name `Sprites1`
- and finally will add a green circle names `circle`.

Here's the final result

[image]

### Code

Let's see now how to use it.

import SpriteKit

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let textureAtlas0 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites0")
        let texture0 = textureAtlas0.textureNamed("circle")
        let sprite0 = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture0)
        sprite0.position.y = 100
        addChild(sprite0)

        let textureAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites1")
        let texture1 = textureAtlas1.textureNamed("circle")
        let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture1)
        sprite1.position.y = -100
        addChild(sprite1)

    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

### How does it work

Step 1: you load the Sprite Atlas

```
let textureAtlas0 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites0")
```

Step 2: you load a specific texture from the texture atlas

```
let texture0 = textureAtlas0.textureNamed("circle")
```

Step 3: you use your texture as you want

```
let sprite0 = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture0)
sprite0.position.y = 100
addChild(sprite0)
```

Comment: I know this isn’t the right way to ask on stackoverflow but given that you’ve been able to answer two my questions in the past I thought you could help me with this -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/52443919/9649381

Comment: Sure, I'll look at it later.