# increase game speed and keep same distance between nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, game-development

I am working on a game where I have two functions . The first function is used to create a row of obstacles. The gameSpeed variable is used to decide how frequently a new row of obstacles is added. Example : if I set gameSpeed to 3 then a new obstacle row is added every 3 seconds.

```
func addobstalce() {
    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if lastYieldTimeInterval > gameSpeed {
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        nextRow(cR: currentRow)
    }
}
```

and the second function is used to add movement to them. this function has a variable called travelSpeed. I have set travelSpeed to 8 right now.

```
func addMovement (obstacle : SKSpriteNode) {
    let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: obstacle.position.x, y: self.size.height/1.5), duration: TimeInterval(travelSpeed))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let both = [move,remove]
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence(both)
    obstacle.run(moveAndRemove)
}
```

so when above code is executed a new obstacle is added every three seconds and that obstacle takes 8 seconds to go from the bottom of screen to top of screen.

but as my game progresses I want to increase the speed of the whole game. I can change travelSpeed and gameSpeed variables  but when I do so the distance between two obstacles does not remain same. How should I increase speed  of my game while keeping the distance between two obstacles same.

I am using a switch statement to regulate the travelSpeed and gameSpeed variables but I am willing to use other methods as well.

```
switch obstaclesMade {
    case 10:
        //  increase speed by changing travelSpeed and/or gameSpeed
    case 20:
        //  increase speed by changing travelSpeed and/or gameSpeed
    case 30:
        //  increase speed by changing travelSpeed and/or gameSpeed
    default:
        break
}
```

Here is the function that adds obstacles

```
        func addRow (type :rowType){
        let obst1 = addObstacle(type: .small)
        let obst2 = addObstacle(type: .small)
        let obst3 = addObstacle(type: .small)
        obst1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + obst1.size.width/2, y: obst1.position.y)
        obst2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: obst1.position.y)
        obst3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - obst1.size.width/2, y: obst1.position.y)
        addChild(obst1)
        addChild(obst2)
        addChild(obst3)
        addMovement(obstacle: obst1)
        addMovement(obstacle: obst2)
        addMovement(obstacle: obst3) }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nodes have a speed variable

Comment: Yeah I can set obstacle.speed but how I make sure that the distance between two obstacles remains same.

Comment: Because speed does not change distance.....

Comment: if i use obstacle.speed to then that will only make the obstacles get to the top faster. I need to know how do i calculate the rate of obstacle generation so that i am able to generate new obstacles faster to compensate for the increased movement speed of the obstacles.

Comment: Again, you use the speed variable so that it creates your obstacles faster

Comment: earlier obstacles were being made every 3 seconds and took 8 seconds to get to top. if i increase speed and set it to lets say 6 then obstacles are going to take 6 seconds to get to top which is two seconds faster. but because = obstacles are still being made every 3 seconds the distance between any two obstacles will bee different. How do I figure out the new generation time so that I am able to generate obstacles to keep up with speed.

Comment: You dont change the generation time, you just increase the speed of the node that is running the generation action

Comment: I am not using a node for generation of obstacles. I am using an if stateement that checks for time intervals. If it has been more than 3 seconds since an obstacle was added, the if statement executes a function that adds new obstacle. so i cant use speed variable on an if statement or on a function. I've edited the question and added the function that adds branches and is called when the if statement is executed.

Comment: Well, now you know how to change your code to get it to work properly lol